# ERROR: Failed to process XAP file - Windows Phone 8 Cordova project

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am having trouble running the Store Test Kit on my Cordova Windows Phone 8 app, using Visual Studio 2013. I can deploy to the device fine, but when it comes to submitting I get the following error:

[image]

I have tried to rebuild the project multiple times, closed and opened the test kit and visual studio but no luck. Looking around the internet, similar problems were occurring but nothing worked.

I have tried renaming the XAP file created, and even changing its extension to a .zip to find incorrect files that may be causing problems, but nothing.

After rebuilding my project I don't receive an errors of any kind so I am totally stumped!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any 0-byte sized files in your .xap package?

Try just deleting those from the .xap directly and re-running Store Test Kit.